# Come si rende in italiano l'espressione "Flattery, like perfume, should be smelled, not swallowed"?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Questa epressione è una metafora che si riferisce alle persone che prendono per vero un complimento fatto in ironia e se ne compiacciono. A me non è venuto in mente niente di corrispondente in italiano, spero possiate aiutarmi voi.

Comment: Ho anche trovato un aforisma di Charles Clark Munn: *Compliments are like perfume, to be inhaled, not swallowed*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ho trovato questo [aforisma](https://www.pensieriparole.it/aforismi/comportamento/frase-50157) che mi sembra si avvicini al senso di quello americano:

> I complimenti sono come i funghi, spesso i più belli sono anche i più velenosi.

(pensieriparole.it)